# Creaet VIEW but alter data type for selected columns

Tags: mysql, sql, view

I have successfully created a MySQL View but have just noticed that the data type for most of the columns is "longtext". I need to change some of these to integers but it looks like you can't change the data type for the View columns after the View has been created.

Is it possible to specify the data type for individual columns when creating the View? Here's my SQL query:

```
select p.ID as order_id,
       p.post_date,
       max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_email' and p.ID = pm.post_id
                     THEN pm.meta_value END) as billing_email,
       max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_first_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id
                     THEN pm.meta_value END) as _billing_first_name,
       max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_billing_last_name' and p.ID = pm.post_id
                     THEN pm.meta_value END) as _billing_last_name,
       max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_total' and p.ID = pm.post_id
                     THEN pm.meta_value END) as order_total,
       max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_order_tax' and p.ID = pm.post_id
                     THEN pm.meta_value END) as order_tax,
       max(CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_paid_date' and p.ID = pm.post_id
                     THEN pm.meta_value END) as paid_date
from wp_posts as p,
     wp_postmeta as pm
where post_type = 'shop_order'
  and p.ID = pm.post_id
  and
  and post_status = 'wc-completed'
group by p.ID
```

I would like the order_tax and order_total columns to be integers (e.g. bigint(20)). I'm new to SQL in general and haven't been able to find the syntax if this is possible?

Comment: Try this: max(... ) + 0 as order_tax,

Comment: I guess NO.
You should be changing Data type for the columns of the Tables , you have created a VIEW for.
Views is Just a SELECT statements on Tables.

Comment: And if you're now allowed to alter the base tables, do CAST in the view definition.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks - I was able to get the View data types set correctly by using CAST, e.g.:

```
    CAST(max( CASE WHEN pm.meta_key = '_line_subtotal' and p.order_item_id = pm.order_item_id THEN pm.meta_value END ) AS UNSIGNED) as subtotal
```